# Set brightness of flash lamp/LED with an ESP32

Tags: led, esp32, c++

This sketch is to turn on and turn off an LED flash (torch) on board ESP32S camera periodically

```
#define LAMPU_FLASH 4

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LAMPU_FLASH, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(LAMPU_FLASH, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LAMPU_FLASH, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}
```

I think that flash lamp is too bright. Since the program is digital, I wonder if I can dynamically set the brightness of the flash. If reducing brightness is not possible, can PWM handle it?

Comment: We don't know how your ESP32 controls your lamp, so with this info it cannot be answered if brightness control is available via PWM or some other method. Please add schematics of your design.

Comment: Have you checked to see if IO 4 is connected to the PWM module?

Comment: Words like "PWM" are not magic wands, and interact with the real world, which is where the schematic becomes absolutely necessary. A picture is worth a thousand words -- may we please have a picture (schematic) of your circuit?  (As accurate as you can make it, please.)

Comment: If this is a "standard" ESP32-Cam with its Flash LED on pin 4, then the brightness of the Flash LED can be controlled with `ledcSetup()`, `ledcAttachPin()` and `ledcWrite()`. There are many sites that explain how to use these.

Comment: Why should I show schematic diagram, Its diagram is just ```ESP32 -> USB to TTL (UART) -> Laptop```. LED Flash is on board which it is built-in LED FLASH on GPIO 4.